# Inserting data into XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, insert, elementtree

I'm working with specific sets of data that I want to insert into an existing file in a fixed section. I want to alter the XML file from looking like this:

```
<SBEDataUploadFile>
   <ApplicationData>
      <firmware>
         <SoftwareVersion>1.0</SoftwareVersion>
         <BuildDate>Dec  1 2012 10:43:42</BuildDate>
         </firmware>
      </ApplicationData>
</SBEDataUploadFile>
```

to look like this:

```
<SBEDataUploadFile>
<![CDATA[
** Location 001
** Latitude In 18.33885
** Longitude In 64.97647
** Time In 11:55
** Depth (ft) 10
** Line Out (ft) 5
** Time Out 11:56
** Latitude Out 18.33885
** Longitude Out 64.97647
** Notes
]]>
   <ApplicationData>
      <firmware>
         <SoftwareVersion>1.0</SoftwareVersion>
         <BuildDate>Dec  1 2012 10:43:42</BuildDate>
         </firmware>
      </ApplicationData>
   </SBEDataUploadFile>
```

I tried this with `xml.etree.ElementTree`, but my result is that it appends the comment to the bottom after the `</ApplicantionData>`. Here's my current code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#variables
location = "BPT"
latitude_in = 0
longitude_in = 0
time_in = 0
depth = 0
line_out = 0
time_out = 0
latitude_out = 0
longitude_out = 0
notes = ""

#formatting and converting all variables to string
toString = "<![CDATA["+"\n"+"** Location "+location+"\n"+"** Latitude In "\
+str(latitude_in)+"\n"+"** Longitude In "+str(longitude_in)+"\n"+\
"** Time In "+str(time_in)+"\n"+"** Depth (ft) "+str(depth)+"\n"+"** Line Out (ft) "\
+str(line_out)+"\n"+"** Time Out "+str(time_out)+"\n"+"** Latitude Out "\
+str(latitude_out)+"\n"+"** Longitude Out "+str(longitude_out)+"\n"+"** Notes "+notes+"\n"+"]]>"

xml_filepath = xmlfilepath.xml
xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_filepath)
xml_root = xml_tree.getroot()
ET.SubElement(xml_root, toString)

print ET.tostring(xml_root)
```

and these are my current results:

```
<SBEDataUploadFile>
   <ApplicationData>
      <firmware>
         <SoftwareVersion>1.0</SoftwareVersion>
         <BuildDate>Dec  1 2012 10:43:42</BuildDate>
         </firmware>
      </ApplicationData>
   <<![CDATA[
** Location BPT
** Latitude In 0
** Longitude In 0
** Time In 0
** Depth (ft) 0
** Line Out (ft) 0
** Time Out 0
** Latitude Out 0
** Longitude Out 0
** Notes 
]]> /></SBEDataUploadFile>
```

I want this to be able to make it look like my desired results and get rid of that extra `/>` right before the `</SBEDataUploadFile>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `SubElement`. Just set the text node on the root element:

```
xml_root.text = toString
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!, I just love where i'm so close to close to the answer but no cigar. Thank you!!!.